# Iterative mergesort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, iteration, mergesort

i'm currently working on iterative version of mergesort, but i've encountered a problem. The program crashes when there are specific sizes of array's like 34,35,36 or 100(just few examples) and it works for the rest(fe works for powers of 2). I've ran some tests and debugged it, and the problem seems to be with the ranges of my iterations/left,right halves of mergesort, but i can't find it. I'll be thankful for your help.
Code:

```
int * loadArray(int size){ //i input size of array and it assigns random numbers
    int *array = new int[size];

     srand( time( NULL ) );

    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        array[i]=rand()%100;

    return array;
}




void merge(int arr[], int left, int middle, int right)
{
    int i, j, k;              //iterators
    int n1 = middle-left + 1; //indexes
    int n2 = right-middle;    //indexes
    int Left[n1], Right[n2];  //arrays holding halves

for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    Left[i] = arr[left + i];//assigning values to left half
for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    Right[j] = arr[middle + 1+ j];//assigning values to right half

i = 0;
j = 0;
k = left;
while (i < n1 && j < n2)    //comparing and merging
{
    if (Left[i] <= Right[j])
    {
        arr[k] = Left[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[k] = Right[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

while (i < n1)  //leftovers
{
    arr[k] = Left[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

while (j < n2)  //leftovers
{
    arr[k] = Right[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}
}




void mergeSortIter(int array[], int size) //the function which is being called and handles division of the array
{
    double startTime = clock(); //start measuring time

    int i;
    int left_start;

   for (i=1; i<=size-1; i = 2*i)
   {
       for (left_start=0; left_start<size-1; left_start += 2*i)
       {
            int mid = left_start + i - 1;
            int right_end = min(left_start + 2*i - 1, size-1);
            merge(array, left_start, mid, right_end);
       }
       //showArray(array,size);
   }
    cout << double( clock() - startTime ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< " seconds." << endl; //output the time measured
}
```

Comment: `int Left[n1], Right[n2]; `  This is not valid ANSI C++.  Arrays must be declared using compile-time expression, not runtime values.  Also, your code has a gigantic memory leak.  Use `std::vector` instead of arrays -- that takes care of both the memory leak and the non-standard C++ code.

Comment: Considering memory leak - I delete the array in main afterwards. What do you mean that it's not standard ANSI? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: You cannot declare arrays that have the number of indices as a runtime value.  Your compiler supports a non-standard extension called *Variable Length Arrays* (VLA's).  Compile with the appropriate ANSI switches, and you will get the compiler error stating as such (if it's gcc, it should be `-Wall -pedantic`).

Comment: Also, **don't test with random numbers.** -- If you have a problem with a sorting routine, always test with a known set of numbers that can duplicate the problem.  By testing with random numbers, you will have a much harder time pinpointing what the issue is because the numbers will keep changing each time you run the program.

Comment: [Here is a complete example](http://ideone.com/baz9WA), using `std::vector`, and showing there is a big issue that your faux (I call it that) array version is not showing you.  The value of `n2` in your array declaration is negative on that data set.  By contrast, [here is your original VLA version](http://ideone.com/5d7NDb) (the online compiler supports VLA).   The error is totally hidden from you when you resort to non-standard syntax.

Comment: Oh, and here is the [Visual Studio](http://rextester.com/PPL99102) error when trying to compile an array declared with a variable number of entries.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay, so i've read about VLA's and ANSI a little and came to this: `int *tab_helper = new int[(end-start+1)];` instead of what i had. It works now, but now I'll encounter memory leak, it seems. Am i heading the right way or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Just use `std::vector`, like in the link I gave you.  Then there is no memory leak.  The `std::vector` is the C++ dynamic array class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay, so I used it as you suggested and I can now see the bad alloc, that you were speaking about. Now, how can i fix it?

Comment: It isn't the bad alloc that you should focus on.  Look at the output that was generated each time that function was called.  Do you see the `-2`?  That shows that your values you were sending were totally off.  You weren't really expecting to declare an array with `-2` entries, right?

Comment: That is true, however what bugs me is why this works for arrays with size lower than ten and gets ridiculous after it? Negative array is certainly not what i'm looking for. And concerning that - as an index of an array, wouldn't it be a result of bad iterations instead of memory? (although they are correct, seems like i'm just lost).

Comment: The vector can't create -2 entries, so an exception is thrown.  A VLA for some reason gladly went on as if nothing was wrong (when indeed something is wrong).  The emphasis should be on fixing your merge sort, given that you see it doesn't work now, regardless of whether you're using vectors, VLA's, `new[]`, etc.  If you went through the code by hand (or better yet -- a debugger), you would see the same thing -- your logic gave the function a negative index.

Comment: You might want to use [wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) as a guide.