# C++ Binary Bar Code Assignment

Tags: c++, barcode

I'm in an introductory course for computer science, and using C++.

Our assignment is to create different "bar code scanners" - binary, code 39 and code 48. This is code for the binary portion, where a barcode is made of alternative black and white stripes, where each stripe is either wide or narrow. Wide bars are interpreted as 1, and narrow bars as 0.

The guidelines for the assignment are:

- Read a number b indicating the number of bars in the code (an odd integer 1 ≤ b ≤ 21 )
- Read b characters, one at a time
- Each character will be either w for wide or n for narrow
- Wide bars are a 1, narrow bars are a 0
- Convert the bar code into its equivalent number and display the number

I felt like my code was okay, but it won't return anything longer than 6 digits. If I enter b as anything between 7 and 21, it still asks for that many integers, but only prints 6 of them.

Thanks for your help!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int b; //number of bars
int i = 0; //loop variables
int k = 0;
int l = 0;

cout << "Number of bars in code (between 1 and 21): " ;
cin >> b;
char arraychars[b]; //barcode as w's and n's
int arrayint[b]; //whole barcode as ints
while (b <= 21 && b >= 1) //b is in range
{
    for (i=0; i<b; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter character (w for wide, n for narrow): " << endl;
        cin >> arraychars[i];
    }
    for (k=0; k<b; k++)
    {
        if (arraychars[k] == 'w')
            arrayint[k] = 1;
        else if (arraychars[k] == 'n')
            arrayint[k] = 0;
        else
            break;
    }
    for (l=0; l<b; l++) //prints
        cout << arrayint[l] ;
        break; //exits loop
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how it manages ever to print any more than *one* digit, given that after outputting any digit the next thing you do is `break;` which exits the loop.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem you're having (unless by coincidence) but your second loop is using `i` as its upper bound. It just so happens that after the first loop `i` equals `b` but you should really be using `b`. Also, you've got an inclusive upper bound (`k<=i`) when you surely want an exclusive one (`k<i`, or rather `k<b`): can you see why?

Comment: Your output will be in binary. Is that actually what you were asked to do, or were you supposed to treat the binary 0s and 1s as the bits of an integer and output that integer in decimal?

Comment: It is supposed to be in binary, as 010101. The `break;` is an error, as is the inclusive bound. I will change it. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two lines of `main()` should already raise warnings galore. The point is that arrays in C++ are statically sized, and here, you create an array who's size is determined from the value of `b` which hasn't been initialized before. Heaven knows what the compiler makes of this. Replace this with a `std::vector` or `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare your array after `"int b;"`;

```
int b; //number of bars
int i = 0; //loop variables
int k = 0;
int l = 0;
cout << "Number of bars in code (between 1 and 21): " ;
cin >> b;

char *arraychars = new char[b]; //barcode as w's and n's
int *arrayint = new int[b]; //whole barcode as ints

while (b <= 21 && b >= 1) //b is in range
{
    for (i=0; i<b; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter character (w for wide, n for narrow): " << endl;
        cin >> arraychars[i];
    }
    for (k=0; k<b; k++)
    {
        if (arraychars[k] == 'w')
            arrayint[k] = 1;
        else if (arraychars[k] == 'n')
            arrayint[k] = 0;
        else
            break;
    }
    for (l=0; l<b; l++) //prints
        cout << arrayint[l] ;
        break; //exits loop
}
return 0;
}
```

otherwise your variable b take value is not clear.

you can not know how size of the arrays

Comment: `char arraychars[b];` is not standard.  The op should use a `std::vector` or use a `std::unique_ptr<>`.

Comment: @NathanOliver  One reason to **not** use VLA's --  Look at this question to show that using VLA's [hides bugs that could be detected by vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678841/iterative-mergesort-in-c#comment60948939_36678841)